# Jasper Server logged out when editing a big domain

Tags: jasperserver

So my company is using Jasper Server 6 and we are running into this problem of editing a very big domain (lots of tables). If I choose **Edit with Domain Designer…**, the designer will open up, but as soon as I click any tab (table, or derived table,...), I get the "The connection was reset" error page. On some of our clients, we got kick out of the session and had to login again.

What is the cause of this and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the value of maxPostSize of the Connector element in the conf/server.xml file in the Tomcat home directory. The default value is 2MB and you can either increase it or set to "0" or "-1" depending on your version of Tomcat to disable the POST size limit.

### Per Jaspersoft Community forum:

https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/while-navigating-domain-designer-tabs-large-domain-it-redirects-login-page

### Issue Description

A customer was attempting to edit a huge domain, and when browsing through their loadbalancer or proxy the browser would hang, and when bypassing the proxy (hitting JRS directly) the browser would redirect to the login page. Analysis of the jasperserver.log showed an error from CsrfGuard:

error:required token is missing from the request

### Resolution

The error means that the OWASP_CSRFTOKEN is being lost from the http POST which occurs while browsing from one tab to another in the domain designer. From viewing example POSTS of other domains we can see the OWASP_CSRFTOKEN token is one of the last items added to the http POST body. Since there is no proxy or loadbalancer the primary way for the OWASP_CSRFTOKEN to be lost is due to tomcat truncating the end of the POST body due to it's maxPostSize. In Tomcat's server.xml, edit the Connector element, adding a value larger than the total POST size, for example:

```
<Connector port="8070"
       protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       maxPostSize="20000000"
       redirectPort="8443" />
```